# Mouse over specific section

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have a `<div>`, and in jQuery I want to divide this square in two, in fact I want the hover event over the top left area.

I want the red area.

http://jsfiddle.net/wGGgx/1/

It this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2wkF/

You have to use `mousemove` instead of `hover`, since hover gets only fired once.

Comment: Well it's still not a simple shape detection and this relies on calculating the position of the mouse relative to the object. Bottom line for any solution to this question is that it can't be don't without some sort of coordinate check.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done this way since you're dealing with rectangular objects even if they look like triangles with the way you're coloring the borders. I tried positioning two separate divs in a container div just to see if playing with absolutely positioned elements made a difference and it didn't -- same rectangular element issue.

Why not use an imagemap instead?